# tensorboard doesn't show graphs

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

Hello guys, since I moved to TF 1.0 (with GPU) I haven't been able to get graph results from Tensorboard. I was trying to plot old event files (that TF 0.10 produced and I could see in older versions) and I didn't get anything. I made a simple code in the new version and still have the same problem. In version 0.10 I was working with Mozilla Firefox and the results were shown. Someone in a group said that Chrome could solve the problem, but I cannot see absolutely anything there.

[image: Cannot see data]

If someone experienced and solved the same error, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the newest version of TensorBoard? The file format might have changed between 0.10 and 1.0. If you have old files, you might benefit from using an older TensorBoard to inspect them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, that's good to know then... however I tried to plot a new event file (created under tf 1.0) and the same screen with no data appeared.

Comment: Are you passing the correct path to the log files when running tensorboard?

Answer (score 0):

I concur.

I've experienced the same on one remote system yesterday. TensorFlow 1.0.1 GPU with Python 3 from dockerhub repository. Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu. It doesn't show scalar graphs (though it shows network graph).

I've made sure event files have summaries in them. I tested it on two other systems: macOS+Anaconda+Python3+Tensorflow1.0.1-GPU and on Ubuntu+Chrome+NVidia-Docker+Tensorflow1.0.1-GPU-py3 and it works there.

I have no clue what causes it on one machine and what to do to fix it yet :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. wojtekcz. Your response doesn't explain how you've made sure event files have summaries in them, or how to solve the user's problem. If you have experience with this problem, sharing your own research about the issue would be better as an answer.

Be sure to check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.